# Using LuaTeX, HSRM beamer theme, fontspec says DANTE font not found. .sty file has no reference to DANTE

Tags: beamer, luatex, fontspec

I am attempting to modify the HSRM beamer theme found [here](https://github.com/hsrmbeamertheme/hsrmbeamertheme). After switching from pdftex to LuaTex and purchasing the Flama fonts, I thought I would be ready to go. However, that seems not to be the case. I am now getting an error saying:

```
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "DANTE" cannot be found.
!  
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
```

It says that I should find a reference to DANTE on line 140 here:

```
l.140   \newfontface\DANTEFONT{DANTE}
```

But I don't see that in either the .sty file or the .tex.

I am using the hsrm-beamer-demo.tex and .sty files, not the minimal ones.

Can anyone help me figure out where the heck I'm going wrong?

I'm on a Mac and I'm using Mactex and emacs if that makes any difference.

Comment: The font DANTE will be uploaded to CTAN (hopefully) in the next few days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File `hsrm-beamer-demo.tex` loads package `dtklogos`, which contains in lines 138 to 147:

```
\ifluatex
  \RequirePackage{fontspec}
  \newfontface\DANTEFONT{DANTE}
  \providecommand*\DANTE[1][]{\DANTEFONT DANTE}
\else
  \providecommand*\DANTE[1][]{%
      \begingroup
        \usefont{OT1}{dante}{m}{n}\selectfont DANTE%
      \endgroup}
\fi
```

`DANTE` is a special font for typesetting the name/logo of the German TeX user group "DANTE e.V.". It is used in the journal ["Die TeXnische Komödie"](http://www.dante.de/DTK_en.html) published by the user group.

AFAIK the font is not publicly available. I have addressed it to the presidium around three times with a positive feedback, but nothing happened so far, it is not on CTAN. Probably a low priority/no time issue.

As workaround, the `dtklogos.sty` can be copied to a new name, e.g. `mydtklogos.sty`. There the problematic line can be disabled or removed.

Comment: Well I guess that would make sense as to why I couldn't find any information on English language sites. Where do I find the `dtklogos.sty`file?

Comment: @black_sheep07 Since you have already used it, it is installed on your system. In TeX Live and MiKTeX it is part of distribution package `dtk`. It is available on CTAN, again as [dtk](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/dtk).

Comment: Ah. How do I modify this?

Comment: @black_sheep07 Putting a `%` at the front of the line or by deleting the line.

Comment: I mean how do I modify the `dtklogos.sty` file? I'm not entirely sure where in the file system I should look.

Comment: @black_sheep07 (a) The `.log` file should contain the full path in both MiKTeX and TeX Live. (b) On the command line: `kpsewhich dtklogos.sty` (c) Search facility of the operating system